# Sum of all subparts of an array of integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, big-o, subset

Given an array `{1,3,5,7}`, its subparts are defined as  `{1357,135,137,157,357,13,15,17,35,37,57,1,3,5,7}`.
I have to find the sum of all these numbers in the new array. In this case sum comes out to be 2333.
Please help me find a solution in `O(n)`. My `O(n^2)` solution times out.

link to the problem is [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SUBSHARD/) or [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/POWERSUM/).

My current attempt( at finding a pattern) is

```
for(I=0 to len) //len is length of the array
{
     for(j=0 to len-i)
     {
          sum+= arr[I]*pow(10,j)*((len-i) C i)*pow(2,i)
     }
}
```

In words - len-i C i  = (number of integers to right) C weight.   (combinations {from permutation and combination})
2^i = 2 power (number of integers to left)

Thanks

Comment: also note that length of array can be large. Any hints on how to make a solution keeping that and time complexity in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily solve this problem with a simple recursive.

```
def F(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return (arr[0], 1)
    else:
        r = F(arr[:-1])
        return (11 * r[0] + (r[1] + 1) * arr[-1], 2 * r[1] + 1)
```

So, how does it work? It is simple. Let say we want to compute the sum of all subpart of {1,3,5,7}. Let assume that we know the number of combinatiton of {1,3,5} and the sum of subpart of {1,3,5} and we can easily compute the {1,3,5,7} using the following formula:

> SUM_SUBPART({1,3,5,7}) = 11 * SUM_SUBPART({1,3,5}) + NUMBER_COMBINATION({1,3,5}) * 7 + 7

This formula can easily be derived by observing. Let say we have all combination of {1,3,5}

```
A = [135, 13, 15, 35, 1, 3, 5]
```

We can easily create a list of {1,3,5,7} by

```
A = [135, 13, 15, 35, 1, 3, 5] + 
    [135 * 10 + 7, 
     13  * 10 + 7, 
     15  * 10 + 7, 
     35  * 10 + 7, 
     1   * 10 + 7, 
     3   * 10 + 7, 
     5   * 10 + 7] + [7]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D
Nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could look at at the subparts as sums of numbers:

```
 1357 = 1000*1 + 100*3 + 10*5 + 1*7  
 135 =  100*1  + 10*3  + 1*5  
 137 =  100*1  + 10*3  + 1*7
```

etc..

So, all you need to do is sum up the numbers you have, and then according to the number of items work out what is the multiplier:

Two numbers `[x, y]`:

```
 [x, y, 10x+y, 10y+x]
```

=> your multiplier is 1 + 10 + 1 = 12

Three numbers `[x, y, z]`:

```
[x, y, z, 
 10x+y, 10x+z, 
 10y+x, 10y+z, 
 10z+x, 10z+y, 
 100x+10y+z, 100x10z+y
 .
 . ]
```

=> you multiplier is 1+10+10+1+1+100+100+10+10+1+1=245

You can easily work out the equation for `n` numbers....

Comment: The multiplier won't be the same for all digits since reordering is not allowed. See how 7 is always in the last position?

Comment: one thing, for two numbers - [x, y].. we get : [x, y, 10x+y].. We DONT have 10y+x, or 10z+x, or 10z+y and so on. Im trying to make a pattern, but Im not able to make an O(n) pattern. My current one is O(n^2).

Comment: @Joni - you are right. I thought we are dealing with all options here. In any case, this can still be worked out for each digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand invisal's recursive solution you get this explicit formula:

```
subpart sum = sum for k=0 to N-1:  11^(N-k) * 2^k * a[k]
```

This suggests the following O(n) algorithm:

```
multiplier = 1
for k from 0 to N-1:
    a[k] = a[k]*multiplier
    multiplier = multiplier*2

multiplier = 1
sum = 0
for k from N-1 to 0:
    sum = sum + a[k]*multiplier
    multiplier = multiplier*11
```

Multiplication and addition should be done modulo M of course.